# Plotly Draw a 3d line between two points

Tags: python, plot, 3d, plotly, streamlit

My question is clear. I want to draw 3d line between two points.
I have a set of points
`i_list = [(0,0,0), (5,5,5), (10,10,10)]`
`j_list = [(20,20,20), (25,25,25), (30,30,30)]`

I want to draw a line between (0,0,0) and (20,20,20).
Also, another line between (5,5,5) and (25,25,25).
Last line between (10,10,10) and (30,30,30).
how can i do that with python and plotly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through your list of starting and ending coordinates, and add each pair of points as a `go.Scatter3d` trace:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

i_list = [(0,0,0), (5,5,5), (10,10,10)] 
j_list = [(20,20,20), (25,25,25), (30,30,30)]

fig = go.Figure()
for start, end in zip(i_list, j_list):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(
        x=[start[0], end[0]], 
        y=[start[1], end[1]], 
        z=[start[2], end[2]],
        mode='lines'
    ))

fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, it is possible to do this relatively simply with `matplotlib` without the need for `plotly`. All the user has to do is identify the points correctly and it's done...

here is an example for which solves the question above:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# lists of points
i_list = [(0,0,0), (5,5,5), (10,10,10)]
j_list = [(20,20,20), (25,25,25), (30,30,30)]


for i in range(3):
    # example of (0,0,0) -> (20,20,20)
    # example of (5,5,5) -> (25,25,25)
    # example of (10,10,10) -> (30,30,30)
    xs = [i_list[i][0],j_list[i][0]]
    ys = [i_list[i][1],j_list[i][1]]
    zs = [i_list[i][2],j_list[i][2]]

    # Plot contour curves
    ax.plot(xs, ys, zs)


plt.show()
```

The result is this:

[image]

Comment: @Muhammed Sevinçtekin specifically asked for a plotly based solution. while your solution could be helpful, I would imagine that they have a reason they want to use plotly (such as the interactivity and the ability to toggle between traces). the lines also overlap each other and in matplotlib there would be no way to tell

Comment: @DerekO,  point noted on plotly vs matplotlib, which is why i made this clear. Regarding the lines; the example required 3 lines which do **mathematically overlap irrespective of the module** used (as you have already shown).

Comment: yeah I understand that they overlap mathematically, but in plotly you have the ability to toggle between each of the traces so you can see the full extent of each line segment whereas in matplotlib overlap is indistinguishable from line segments that start and end at the same coordinates. I imagine this is at least part of the reason why OP asked for a plotly based solution.